# App composer doesn't exist after a composer update

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I made some changes on my .env file to configure the email,and after a config:clear and composer update my project wont work.

$reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
"Class app\Http\View\Composers\AppComposer does not exist"

Been trying to fix but could't find any solution

Comment: How are you trying to load the AppComposer? What have you tried so far? There is a lot of information missing to help debug.

Comment: I did a php artisan config:cache because I have added a package to send emails with mailtrap, after the config:cache and run php artisan serve it throws this error       `$reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);`    Arguments
"Class app\Http\View\Composers\AppComposer does not exist"

Comment: Also there are some other errors like this one Arguments C:\wamp64\www\Legalizaciones\public\index.php    I think now I'm gonna try to remove the packages that I've installed and the configuration of the email server

Answer (score 0):

```sh
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

then try, but composer update  is not a best practice

```sh
composer update
```

Comment: delete your vendor folder and then composer install again. that is view composer issue inside service provider.